# Issue with displaying TextView in real-time using asyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, real-time, textview

I am learning how to use asyncTask and I have issue with trying to display the TextView in real-time.  The mainActivity have few buttons that will start new activity plus a TextView that show the value that changes for every 200 milliseconds.  But the issue is that the TextView doesn't show up until I click on button to start another activity, and the value doesn't changes when I pressed "back button" to return to mainActivity.  However, it does changes the value when I press button to start another activity.

```
private TextView t;
private int counter;
private boolean isUiVisible = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.counter);
    counter = 0;
}

@Override
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    isUiVisible = true;
    new UpdateUi().execute();
}

@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    isUiVisible = false;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

private class UpdateUi extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        while (true) {
            if (isUiVisible) {
                counter++;
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(200);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                // Ensure the asynkTask ends when the activity ends
                break;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        t.setText(counter + "");
    }
}

public void callRed(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, RedActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void callYellow(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, YellowActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

I have tried setText in onProgressUpdate, but it showed nothing.  I also searched to see if other have issues, but it seems that they do have same issue as mine (one was onClickListener, which was not what I was looking for).

Comment: Firstly, Try to do this `onResume()` instead of doing on `onStart()`. Untile and uncless the ew activity completely hides the old one, onStart() might not be called
`@Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        isUiVisible = true;
        new UpdateUi().execute();
    }`

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't resolve the issue that I have.  But the type-a1pha's answer resolved the issue.  Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `TextView` doesn't show up probably because it has no text inside it...cannot tell for sure without looking at the layout.xml file.

You got that behaviour because the variable `isUiVisible` becomes false only when `onPause()` is called, that is when you switch activity. At that point the `AsyncTask` exits his `doInBackground` method and executes `onPostExecute` which puts some text in the `TextView` making it appears.

To try to fix your code you should call `publihProgress()` inside `doInBackground` and then use `onProgressUpdate` to update your `TextView` in the UIThread.

Comment: Your suggestion worked and it is precisely what I was looking for.  Thank you so much for the explanation, it helped me to understand the behavior better.  :)